# constraints on parameter values in api.ai

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have defined an intent and some parameters within that intent. Those parameters have been marked as "required" and I was wondering is there a way, I can constraint the values for these parameters so that if user enters something which is not in the constrained range then agent , shall ask again for the value.

any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you define parameters in your entities?
For example: cities (New York, Melbourne). If user types "Sydney" then the api.ai keeps asking until you type "New York" or "Melbourne".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Dialogflow's built-in entities you cannot control the values for entities accepted by Dialogflow but can validate these values in your fulfillment with a webhook or Dialogflow's built-in Firebase functions editor

If you're using custom entities you can simply limit the values of the entities to the values you'd like the user to be able to choose after making sure entity expansion is disabled.